# how to keep both activities on the screen in android?

Tags: java, android

Hi In my app i have two activities. one is the main activity. so when i launch the app it invokes the main activity.  the main activity displays on the top left corner of the screen with some width and height. on the main activity there is a button. when i press the button it launches the second activity. when the second activity is launched it displays itself in the center of the screen. When second activity got the focus, the first activity goes to the pause state but it is still displayed on the screen. But when i move from the second activity to the first activity, the first activity gains focus. The problem is when the first activity gains focus, the second activity disappears from the screen. What i want is it should not disappear. It has to be on the screen in pause state. Then I need to switch between these activities.

The following is my manifest file:-

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:name="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:name="com.example.firstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    </application>
```

The two actions uses Linear layout as their root layout and contains some gui elemnts.

Comment: use fragments.http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fragments.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Example at the developer site.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example

EDIT:

When you h navigate to second Activity from first activity, first activity will be paused (will be there on back stack).Your second activity is put on stack and takes focus. When you return to first activity second activity is popped form the stack and destroyed. Now first activity takes focus. This is how it works. Stack works like last in, first out. (LIFO).

For more detail regarding activity back stack read the topic in the link below.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Hi i am not asking to keep both activities in focus. what i am asking is i want bot on screen with one in focus. It is happening already. when first activity launches the second one, the first activity still displays on the screen in pause state while the second activity in focus. but when i go back to the first activity and when the first activity gains the focus back the second activity disappears from the screen. I just want the other activity also to be in the screen in pause state. I am not asking for both to be in focus.

Comment: Yep. What you're asking for is fragments. There's absolutely no way to do what you're asking with activities.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Fragments.  Vogella has a fantastic tutorial.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: Hi i am not asking to keep both activities in focus. what i am asking is i want bot on screen with one in focus. It is happening already. when first activity launches the second one, the first activity still displays on the screen in pause state while the second activity in focus. but when i go back to the first activity and when the first activity gains the focus back the second activity disappears from the screen. I just want the other activity also to be in the screen in pause state. I am not asking for both to be in focus.

Comment: Yep. What you're asking for is fragments. There's absolutely no way to do what you're asking with activities.